# Exception with CFileDialog (MFC)

Tags: c++, exception, mfc

I had the following lines of C++ code in my program

```
CFileDialog dialog(true);
 CString strFileName=L"";
 INT_PTR nResult = dialog.DoModal();
 if(nResult == IDOK)
  // Exception spotted here
  // Debug information gives me --> dialog = {CFileDialog hWnd=0x00000000}
  // What's the heck?
  strFileName=dialog.GetFolderPath();
```

The problem is: When I execute the program on a PC running Windows XP, there always have an ugly exception which I don't know why it happened. But everything's fine when I copied it to another PC running Windows 7.

I'm desperate. Would you guy please tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call

[DWORD WINAPI CommDlgExtendedError(void);](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646916%28VS.85%29.aspx)

after the instantiation of CFileDialog to check that it is instantiated OK and if not why not.

**Edit:**

You are not able to call GetFolderPath after the dialog is closed which it is when DoModal() returns.  Look at this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh5hz49d%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) under remarks on how to pass a buffer to hold the file names.

Comment: I tried! The function returned 0, indicating everything's OK. :(

Comment: @anhldbk - I have edited my answer. You can not call GetFolderPath after the dialog is closed because hWnd is closed, hence the error.

Comment: Oh, thanks for your advice. But I don't know the reason why the code runs smoothly on Windows 7. That thing's bothered me much. :-?

Answer (score 2):

The fun of building on a Window7 machine, and deploying to XP.

If you trace through the MFC code:

::GetVersion() is called and executes all kinds of different code for Windows Visa and above. i.e. It behaves differently.

So this means that if you called GetPathName, GetFileName, or GetFolderPath after a DoModal in WIN7 it works as you'd expected (like Java). For Windows XP you would be incorrect, and the software crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I could not use GetFolderPath on XP, but GetPathName was ok.